# How to prevent receipeints from seeing which other email addresses have received an email?

Tags: php, events, email

I am using this script to send notificaitons to users friends.  the problem is that all recepieints get to see who else got this email.  How do i tweak the code so the emails still get sent to all but they can't see who else got it?

Code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT email from
    friend_email_ids WHERE my_id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
    }
     echo "";


   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   $emails = array(); 

   if($rows == 0)
   {
   print("");

    }
   elseif($rows > 0)
   {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        array_push($emails, $row['email']);

   {

   $email = $row['email'];


  print("");
  }

  }

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign=>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
mail(implode(",", $emails), "Subject: $subject",
$message, "$headers" );
echo "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `additional_headers` fields to add a `BCC`* address . See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

From the manual page:

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

the "birthdaycheck" email is hidden.

*(Blind Carbon Copy)

In you script it would become something like this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";

////////////pay attention here
$headers .= "BCC: ".implode(",", $emails)."\r\n";
$to = "youremail@domain.com"; //the mail in the "TO", visible to all. there has to be 1.
////////////////////////

$subject = "$full_name added";
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "Hello, <br><br>$full_name posted someth<br><br>";
$message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/signup.php?t=&sign=>Click here.</a><br><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

mail($to, "Subject: $subject",
$message, "$headers" );
echo "";
```

Comment: how can i make it so it fits into my script.  I can't get it to work ifi i use Bcc: in front of the $emails..

Comment: Thanks! It worked partially.  The first recipient doesn't see who else got it.  But the second recipient is able to see who else was sent that email.

Comment: That is weird. Are you sure they are in the BCC list? make sure there's nobody in the `$to` var you don't want to send anything to. maybe `echo`/`print_r` the `$headers` and `$to` instead of calling `mail` to debug?

Comment: my bad.  i confused the emails i was using for testing! sorry. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use `BBC` for all recipients:

> Bcc: recipients get a copy of the email, but their email address is
>   automatically deleted at delivery. Nobody except you and the Bcc:
>   recipient will know that they got a copy, and their email address will
>   not be exposed.

-> http://email.about.com/od/emailmanagementtips/qt/How_to_Send_an_Email_to_Undisclosed_Recipients.htm

Answer (score 1):

Put the actual sending of messages in the loop. That way you will send the e-mail to each recipient individually instead of all at once.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) you'll find that the Bcc feature of mail() is what you need to use.

Like zoy (for multiple peeps):

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: someone@example.com,someone2@example.com,someone3@example.com,someone4@example.com,' . "\r\n";
```

Happy Haxin!

_wryteowl